# UISearchBar Pushing Data Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I have implemented a search bar into my application and am having an issue that I have been trying to fix, but can't seem to find the solution anywhere. When you tap the search bar and type in a state you have the choice to press that state and it take you to the areas in that state. It does take you to the areas, but it takes you to the same information every time.... I will show screen shots below, also I am sorry this is such a long post, I just wanted to be sure that you all understood what I was talking about with the pictures and code.

**Searching for Alabama:**

[image]

**Alabama Results:**

[image]

**Searching for Colorado:**

[image]

**Colorado Results:**

[image]

As you can see it gives me the same results (Alabama results) every time. I want it to give me the results for the state that is pressed(Alabama -> Alabama Areas, Colorado -> Colorado Areas). I know it has something to do in my **prepareForSegue** method, but can't seem to know what exactly to change. I will now post my code below:

**RootTableViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objects;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *results;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;


@end
```

**RootTableViewController.m**

```
#import "RootTableViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"

@interface RootTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootTableViewController
{
NSArray *states;
}

- (NSMutableArray*)objects;
{
if (!_objects)
{
    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

return _objects;
}

- (NSMutableArray*)results;
{
if (!_results)
{
    _results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

return _results;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

states = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alabama", @"Georgia", @"Tennessee", @"Colorado", nil];

[self.objects addObjectsFromArray:states];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)searchThroughData
{
self.results = nil;

NSPredicate *resultsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchBar.text];

self.results = [[self.objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultsPredicate] mutableCopy];
}

- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
[self searchThroughData];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.tableView)
{
    return self.objects.count;
}

else
{
    [self searchThroughData];
    return self.results.count;
}
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//table identifier
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"StateCell";

//creating a cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if (tableView == self.tableView)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self.objects[indexPath.row];
}

else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self.results[indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showStateDetail" sender:self];
}
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

if (self.searchBar.text.length)
{
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO];
}
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showStateDetail"])
{
    NSString *object = nil;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

    if(self.searchDisplayController.isActive)
    {
        indexPath = [[self.searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
        object = self.results[indexPath.row];
    }

    else
    {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    }

    SecondTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.stateName = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}

}
@end
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't have experience with performSegueWithIdentifier, but whenever I have some implementation like this I handle the differentiation based on the selection in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Typically you do something like NSString *selectedState = self.results[indexPath.row]; and then push a view controller with that information so it knows what to filter.

Comment: I figured it out and posted my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my issue out I needed to add this at the bottom of my segue:

```
destViewController.stateName = object;
```

instead of this:

```
destViewController.stateName = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```